# Can anyone please identify this chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount, shift-register

Is from an LED board from a modern Pinball machine. Seems like the output is connected to a 74HC594D legs RCLR and SRCLR.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly ST Microelectronics [STWD100NYWY3F watchdog timer](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/06/6a/b3/83/9a/c7/4f/22/CD00176077.pdf/files/CD00176077.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00176077.pdf). However other SOT23-5 ICs could bear this marking, so this is by no means definitive.

[image: Table of ordering information]

Comment: The decoupling capacitor connected to pin 5 (VCC), and the apparent 10K pullup resistor on pin 1 (WDO), would appear to support your theory.

Comment: It was actually the chip JYelton posted.
I really appreciate it!!